# undefined reference to `boost::system::get_posix_category()'

Tags: boost, linker

```
g++ simple_wget.cpp -lssl -lboost_system -lpthread -lcrypto -lboost_filesystem
/tmp/cc2jNHvk.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
simple_wget.cpp:(.text+0x5eb): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_posix_category()'
simple_wget.cpp:(.text+0x5f5): undefined reference to `boost::system::get_posix_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that in boost 1.38 get_posix_category() was removed. Help me please, what can i do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by adding -static parameter to g++. Why it works so i don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the -static sounds like a bad idea, you can break other parts of your code with it. To use -static you're linked libraries should be compiled using static, sometimes that doesn't happen.

Undefined reference usually indicates boost_system is not found. Add -I/path/to/boost_system.so/.dylib/.dll and or -L/path/to/boost_system.so/.dylib/.dll

You should probably locate boost_system first.